# How to get dictionary keys to display in relation to values

Tags: python

I'm looking to categorize some sentences. To do this, I've created a couple dictionary categories for "Price" and "Product Quality". So far I have the code loop through the words within the category and it displays the word it found.

I'd also like to add the actual category name like "Price" or "Product Quality" depending on the values within those keys.

Is there a way to display the keys for each category. Currently it's just displaying both "Price" and "Product Quality" for everything.

Here is the code:

```
data = ["Great price on the dewalt saw", "cool deal and quality", "love it! and the price percent off", "definitely going to buy"]
words = {'price': ['price', 'compare', '$', 'percent', 'money', '% off'],
         'product_quality': ['quality', 'condition', 'aspect']}


for d in data:
    for word in words.values():
        for s in word:
            if s in d:
                print(id(d), ", ", d, ", ", s, ", ", words.keys())
```

Here is the output as well:

```
4398300496 ,  Great price on the dewalt saw ,  price ,  dict_keys(['price', 'product_quality'])
4399544552 ,  cool deal and quality ,  quality ,  dict_keys(['price', 'product_quality'])
4398556680 ,  love it! and the price percent off ,  price ,  dict_keys(['price', 'product_quality'])
4398556680 ,  love it! and the price percent off ,  percent ,  dict_keys(['price', 'product_quality'])
```

Comment: Do you have examples of input with its desired outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [items()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), which unpacks into (key, value):

```
data = ["Great price on the dewalt saw", "cool deal and quality", "love it! and the price percent off", "definitely going to buy"]
words = {'price': ['price', 'compare', '$', 'percent', 'money', '% off'],
         'product_quality': ['quality', 'condition', 'aspect']}


for d in data:
    for category, word in words.items():
        for s in word:
            if s in d:
                print(id(d), ", ", d, ", ", s, ", ", category)
```

Out:

```
(4338487344, ', ', 'Great price on the dewalt saw', ', ', 'price', ', ', 'price')
(4338299376, ', ', 'cool deal and quality', ', ', 'quality', ', ', 'product_quality')
(4338487416, ', ', 'love it! and the price percent off', ', ', 'price', ', ', 'price')
(4338487416, ', ', 'love it! and the price percent off', ', ', 'percent', ', ', 'price')
```